# understanding this lie algebra question-Any guide please

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

Definition: Given a Lie algebra $L$ and a field $F$, a Lie module of $L$ is a couple $(M,f)$, where $M$ is a vector space and
$f: L\times M\to M$ which satisfies:

1. $f$ is linear in each variable.
2. $f$ satisfies:
   $f([x,y],m)=f(x,f(y,m))-f(y,f(x,m))$.

Question: Let L be a Lie algebra and V a vector space. Let $f : L × V → V$ be a
bilinear map. Define an antisymmetric bilinear operation on $L ⊕ V$ by
the following properties.

1. Its restriction to $L$ is the bracket.
2. Its restriction to $V$ is zero.
3. Its value on a pair $(x, v)$ with $x ∈ L$, $v ∈ V$ , is $f(x, v)$.

Prove that
$L ⊕ V$ is a Lie algebra with respect to the operation defined above if
and only if $f$ describes on $V$ a structure of L-module.

I do understand all the definitions I need but don't realize how to apply them here.
When they say restriction to $L$ (respectively $V$) does it mean $f:L\times L\to V$ or $f:L\to V$?

Comment: By restriction to $L$ and $V$ they are talking about the new bilinear operation. So your new bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]_{V}:L\oplus V \times L\oplus V \to L\oplus V$ acts as the old bracket on $L\times L$, is 0 on $V \times V$ and is equal to $f$ on $L \times V$ (it's antisymmetric so that gives us $V \times L$ as well). So now you've got to show that this new bracket satisfies the rules of a Lie bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "it" in "Its restriction ..." refers to that new bilinear operation
$$(L\oplus V) \times (L\oplus V) \rightarrow L\oplus V$$
which has not been given a name. Maybe call it $\lbrace \cdot,\cdot \rbrace$.

Then "restriction" is actually still a bit ambiguous, but they must mean

$\lbrace (l_1,0) , (l_2,0) \rbrace = ([l_1, l_2],0)$

by 1, and

$\lbrace (0,v_1) , (0,v_2) \rbrace = (0,0)$

by 2, and

$\lbrace (l,0) , (0,v) \rbrace = (0, f(l,v))$

by 3.

---

**Added** in response to comment:
An antisymmetric bilinear $\{ \cdot, \cdot \}$ satisfying the above conditions is necessarily given on general elements by

$$\{ (l_1, v_1), (l_2, v_2)\} = ([l_1,l_2], f(l_1,v_2)-f(l_2,v_1) )$$

Now for one direction, you just check by hand that this satisfies the Jacobi identity

$$\{\{ (l_1, v_1), (l_2, v_2)\}, (l_3, v_3)\} + \{\{ (l_2, v_2), (l_3, v_3)\}, (l_1, v_1)\} + \{\{ (l_3, v_3), (l_1, v_1)\}, (l_2, v_2)\} =0$$

as soon as the two conditions on the map $f$ are satisfied. Of course you can just focus on the second components because we assume the Lie bracket $[, ]$ on $L$ satisfies Jacobi anyway. It's still a bit cumbersome, in total you spell out 12 terms there and see each one is cancelled out by another.

Conversely, to see that $f$ must be as described, assume that $\{ \cdot , \cdot \}$ does satisfy Jacobi, in particular

$$\{\{(l_1,0),(l_2,0)\},(0,v)\} + \{\{(l_2,0),(0,v)\},(l_1,0)\} + \{\{(0,v),(l_1,0)\},(l_2,0)\} =0 $$

and you just check what this means in the second component when written out.

Comment: Thanks, proving the iff was wierd and not trivial to me. I did not manage to show that $L+V$ is a lie algebra, assuming that f describes on V a lie-module. In general $L$ is a lie algebra if it is an algebra that satisfies $[x,x]=0 , \forall x\in L$ and and also the jacobi identity. And the other side was also not clear to me:( can you explain please how to do this?

Comment: Thank you @Torsten Schoeneberg, I did not succeed to finish it:( I am lost with using the assumption that f defines a module, i.e how to apply the definition

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help more without literally writing everything out. What do you get e.g. if you write out $\{\{ (l_1, v_1), (l_2, v_2)\}, (l_3, v_3)\} $, by twice applying the formula in the line before?

Comment: Thanks very much, in the other side, when showing that f descrive on V an $L-module$. Can I use that $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(l,f0,0))=0$ ? I want to show that $f$ satisfies te second identity of an $L-module$. @Torsten Schoeneberg

Comment: Yes, in that direction, $f$ must be bilinear by condition 3, and that implies both these things.